# Help with $7 · 7^{k+2} + 64 · 8^{2k+1}$=$7(7^{k+2} + 8^{2k+1}) + 57 · 8^{2k+1}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Could someone please explain why 7 is being subtracted from 64 in:

$7 · 7^{k+2} + 64 · 8^{2k+1}$
 to make

$7(7^{k+2} + 8^{2k+1}) + 57 · 8^{2k+1}.$

Also, how does $7^{k+2}$ get factored by 7 to make the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that  $64=57+7$, so
$$
64\cdot8^{2k+1}=7\cdot8^{2k+1}+57\cdot8^{2k+1}
$$

Your problem now becomes
$$
7\cdot7^{k+2}+7\cdot8^{2k+1}+57\cdot8^{2k+1}=7(7^{k+2}+8^{2k+1})+57\cdot8^{2k+1}
$$